# The distribution of the elements of an eigenvector of random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices, eigenvector

Suppose a random matrix $A$ with its elements following Gaussian distribution with non-zero mean. We know that the eigenvalues of $A$ have two patches: one is at the real axis that is far away from the origin point, and the other one is in a circle around the origin point. We know that the eigenvector of the first patch is $[1,1,\cdots,1]$, but what is the distribution of the elements of an eigenvector whose corresponding eigenvalue is in the second patch?

Here is a picture of the situation:

[image: An image.]

Comment: This question makes no sense to me.

Comment: The picture is misleading. It shows the locations of eigenvalues, but the question is about something about the eigenvectors. The $\{1,1,...,1\}$ is an approximation. Are you normalizing the eigenvectors, and then do you want to know the distribution of each coordinate?

Comment: @Douglas Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I would be surprised if the marginal distribution of a few of the elements of an eigenvector would be much different from independent Gaussians; have you tried generating some random matrices and testing for this?

Comment: The distribution shown in the picture is the result of a test. We see that it is indeed similar to Gaussian.